# Need clarity in usage of cvCaptureFromFile in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, video-streaming, video-capture

I'm faced with an unusual problem.. I use `CvCapture *URL=cvCaptureFromFile("http://192.168.X.X:8080")` which is supposed to be a link to a Video on the web, to capture the video.

Now the issue is: Even if there is no video or for that matter nothing at that link 
cvCaptureFromFile never returns NULL. I get this message: `[tcp @ 0x609f20] TCP connection to 192.168.X.X:8080 failed: No route to host`. This puts my program into a infinite loop as it fails at `cvQueryFrame(URL)`

Why doesn't it return NULL when nothing is there at the address let alone having a video(there absolutely nothing, not even a PC forget an IPCam that is supposed to stream the video). If I'm able to grab the Error returned by the API, then I can handle other sections.

Please explain why this is happening and how can I grab the error reported by the API.

Comment: I've noticed that the (CvCapture *URL) contains(returns) the same address everytime a address that contains nothing(no video, wrong URL) is passed to cvCaptureFromFile.

Answer (score 3):

In order to handle the error write something like this:

```
CvCapture* URL= cvCaptureFromFile("rtsp://192.168.X.X:8080");  //uses real time streaming protocol instead of http
if(!URL) 
      { 
            exit(1);           
      }
```

Comment: Thanks.. But I guess I mentioned that cvCaptureFromFile() doesn't return NULL in the question. And yet these lines are included..

Comment: @Bhargav and have you tried the rtsp? Also if you can put the name of the file in the url instead of the port, better

Comment: Yes.. I have worked with rtsp.. but I'm not to reproduce the same by passing a wrong rtsp link.. but if this problem occurred for http there's a good possiblity that it may occur for rtsp also..

Comment: How bout using this API I see cvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG() ??

Answer (score 0):

in cv::VideoCapture (the C++ interface to cv::CaptureFromFile), there is a function
    bool isOpened();

The structure is allocated, but you cannot grab frames from it.